# e-commerce for subscriptions - application design dilemma

Tags: uml

I'm designing an application that offers subscribed members premium content.  Therefore the app includes e-commerce functionality so users can purchase subscriptions.  Below is a draft of the UML static diagram so far.
[image]

While writing the DDL for the database table that will hold subscription information it seems like it should have foreign keys to both the Users table and the Payments table.  However, that seems to violate some basic database design concepts because it's possible to determine which payment originated from which user by going through the Orders table.  Is there a better way to design the classes than outlined in the diagram to eliminate redundancy?

Answer (score 1):

- You have redundancy, and really a great one, because you haven't chosen the directions of navigability. No-arrows association means association in BOTH directions. You can use it SOMETIMES, but not on all connections! If Orders will have only one-direction navigation to Payment and User, your problem disappears.
- You haven't connected Cart and Order. Usually they are closely tied 1:(0..1). Or set Order to be a generalization of cart. Cart needs date? Really? But Order should have more info - a message, delivery and things. Or subscriptions have some special logics? Then you haven't it here, too.
- Instead of words 'contains' use aggregations - shared and compositions.
- 'has' should be shown by `dot`/`end ownership`, not by words. As you have them, who has whom?
- 'activates' should be shown (if present at all) as a dependency, apart from association.
- I'd advice do divide user account (for identification/login needs only) and use info (addresses and other stuff).
- items and items in orders are more close. Use generalization, not 'is a'. Also, after ordering the items in Orders are cloned and get fixed price. Where is that?

As it is, the logic of the diagram is not obvious at all. Think about making some more high-level diagram. State machine or even Use Case for the start.